# Messages in java

Tags: java, message

I have a challenge:

Imagine you have a set of messages like this:

Code / Message

200567 = A new user was created
462001 = Unknown client number
...

I'm trying to find the neatest, lightest, and easiest to maintain way to use this messages in java.

The rules are:

1. You need to be able to access the message by its code
2. You need to be able to print the code
3. You need to be able to easily change the number of a code in the future

Other notes:

- The messages can be in a proprieties file, in other file, in a class, or other place (?), whatever you find better.
- The code can be a integer or a string (Like MSG_423456), whatever you find better.

So, anybody has ideas?
(Sorry about my lousy English)

Comment: sneaky, but not going to make it.  you still have to show what you have tried, what you think would work, etc. before people here tell you how to do your (home)work.

Comment: homeworks are meant to be done on your own :p

Comment: lol, it's work without the home :)

Comment: If that is a real job problem I suggest you submit your resume to careers.stackoverflow.com

Comment: I started by using a properties file, the problem is that is hard to refactor. If I need to change a code it will be hard to find all the occurrences in the code (and find and replace with the eyes shut is not an option)

Comment: Then in having the messages hardcoded, like private static String MSG_123456 = "message", the term itself is frightening but is easily refactored. But in that case i cant access the code of the message.

Comment: @Woot4Moo you think i need to get another job? Me too... :P

Comment: @Jose take a look at my solution, enumerations may help you here

Comment: @Woot4Moo ummmm, wait a minute or two, i'm trying to understand how you use such enumeration

Comment: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html  is the oracle page on this :)

Comment: @Woot4Moo After a serious brain lock i finally understood. I like your solution, i will be able to use something like MessageType.MSG_1234.getCode() and getMessage(), and is easy to refactor. I don't know the computational weight of that solution but it doesn't seem to heavy. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would put this in an enumeration.

```
public enum MessageType {
```

`NEW_USER("String 123", "A new user was created");`
 `private String code, message;`

`private MessageType(String code, String message) {`
  `this.code = code;

this.message = message`
 `}`

I would go for enumerations because they are to be checked into source control, typically in the environments where I work the properties file is meant to be configured by the individual.  Such as an ant build properties file.

Comment: Thanks! This is the solution I will use.

Comment: This is an interesting solution, however it does not fill your third requirement, "easily change the number of a code in the future". For any small change in the numbers, you would need to modify your code and recompile it -- not to mention the activities in your source control. I would go for the `ResourceBundle` solution proposed in another answer; it would fit all your requirements.

Comment: @Paulo as I mentioned in my answer the properties file, in my experiences, has been used for the individual.  Of course I have not used `ResourceBundle` so I may be missing something

Answer (score 4):

Go for Properties File. Use [ResourceBundle](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html)

```
200567 A new user was created
462001 Unknown client number
```

Comment: Properies files are the best solution, because it allows you to change the messages, or even use different locales, without changing the code.  You can also override them by putting the properties files in directories earlier or later in the class path.

Comment: the problem in that solution is the refactoring. If i need to change a message code, i will need to navigate though all the source code to find all the places where the message code is used (i think...).

Comment: Thanks, fortunately I don't think I will need local messages in this project. If in the future my bosses change their minds I will cry and regret not to adopt a proprieties file :)

Comment: @Jose Antonio , if you don't need localization then also its good practise to use properties file as you can externally change the message without re compiling as in other case

Comment: @JoseAntonio There is no need to refactor your code if you use this solution, unless everything is hard-coded in your application.

Comment: @PauloGuedes I agree that the proprieties file is the best practice without doubt. But it only allows to change the messages easily. If you want to change the code of a message you need to recompile anyway since you have to change all the places you call for that code.

Comment: @JoseAntonio codes [keys] are generally not meant to change in good design

Comment: @JoseAntonio Why would you ever want to change the code?  As long as it's unique it could be set to ANYTHING and the user would never know the difference.

Comment: @dj_segfault It's a SOA project, so the codes will be sent to the client. And there is some information codified in the code (like one digit represents if the message is an error, an info, ...). Like org.life.java said "codes [keys] are generally not meant to change in good design", but I'm not in control of the design, so I cannot assume that the codes will not be changed by the people controlling the specs or by a client request.

Comment: @Jose Antonio  its ok but but `I'm not in control of the design, so I cannot assume that the codes will not be changed by the people controlling the specs or by a client request` , even it would be easier for client to change property file then code

Answer (score 1):

If I had to implemtn this I would use a HashMap. The code are the keys and the message the values.

Comment: I thought about that but the problem is that you have to do hashmap.put at runtime for all the messages, and it is not easily refactorable.

Comment: Thanks, it's a logic solution and easy to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is probably to have a `HashMap<string, string>` or `HashMap<int, string>` that is a static member of your main class or some other relevant class.  Write a properties file and a simple method that is called near the start of the program to populate the HashMap.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html